# view state not retaining values

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I'm trying to retain "visible" property of a control using view state in the following way

```
public bool showstatusbox {
    get { return Convert.ToBoolean(ViewState["statusbox"]); }
    set { ViewState["statusbox"] = value; }
}
```

Is there anything I should do other than this to retain value. Because, though I store the value in view state, on postback, its becoming null.

Comment: This code looks correct, you should add any other code that is using this property.

Comment: Can you post your aspx/ascx code?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have another peice of code stomping on this? It is essentially a global variable after all.

Comment: You could try making the setter `private` to see if you get an indication of the value being set somewhere else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember having issues with this and resolved it with code like this:

```
protected override object SaveViewState()
{
    return new object[] { 
        TaxRate, 
        SubTotal, 
        Tax, 
        LetterId, 
        ActivityIds, 
        AssociateLettersToInvoice 
    };
}

protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
{
    var array = (object[])savedState;
    TaxRate = (decimal)array[0];
    SubTotal = (decimal)array[1];
    Tax = (decimal)array[2];
    LetterId = (int?)array[3];
    ActivityIds = (string)array[4];
    AssociateLettersToInvoice = (bool)array[5];
}
```

Comment: Can you please briefly explain what you're trying to do above?

Comment: @Rocky - I don't believe I can explain it any better without knowing what is confusing you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you confirmed that EnableViewState is true for the control?

Comment: Okay.  And you're sure that you're checking this variable after a postback?  Since the viewstate is stored on the client as a hidden field, it will only return when the form is posted (SubmitBehavior).